# Reasoning/modeling business logic with the approach of Domain Driven Design

Tags: domain-driven-design

What I'm trying to achieve is to develop an application implementing the DDD approach.

The story might sound silly but it's an actual, real life problem. Believe me.

The business looks as follows:

- Let's say a company specializes in manufacturing sweets which are distributed to its own shops for sale.
- The craftsman makes different types of candy depending on what is - and what is not - currently at the display at one of the company's shop.
- When a basket of one flavour 'disappears' the seller replaces this type of sweet with a different kind from the shops storage cabinet.
- Duplicates of flavours at the display shouldn't exist and the display should be populated with as much as the capacity allows or how much the manafacturer can handle to produce.
- The sweets are distributed from the manufacturer's lab's storage to the shop's one depending on the demand.

Let's assume each worker has public view access to the display and the storage cabinet. Each worker (user) decides on it's own what to provide. The shops display view will be publicly accessible through the application to a potential client as an information what is currently on sale.

So far I have split the business logic into three separate (sub?)domains which are:

- Production
- Distribution
- Sale

And of course each entity like Sweets, Storage, Craftsman, it's Repository etc. are placed respectively in their domain.

The concerns I approach are:

- Is it appropriate that an entity (Sweet) is being passed from one domain to another?
- Should a Provider be able to reach the StorageCabinet of one domain and pass it's content to another?

Is my reasoning proper? Correct me if I'm wrong or violating any DDD rules.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "reach the StorageCabinet of one domain and pass it's content to another" - what do you mean ? Another domain ? Another cabinet ? Isn't the StorageCabinet entity only in the Sale subdomain ?

Comment: @guillaume31: after making the Candy the Craftsman stores it in his own StorageCabinet at his Lab so the Provider knows what to withdraw and deliver to each shops StorageCabinet.

Comment: Which subdomain is Provider part of ? You might want to have a look at the concept of Bounded Context, which is a concrete materialization of a subdomain in the solution space, and the different ways of making BC's talk to each other.

Comment: You talk about DDD but do not use any terms of strategic design like "bounded context" or "aggregate". This leads to some worrying conclusions...

Answer (score 1):

> The story might sound silly but it's an actual, real life problem.

This is great, actually.  In his recent [retrospective](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDW0QWie21s&t=34m55s), one of the things that Greg Young called out is that "shopping cart" models are a really lousy as a teaching tool.  He points out briefly that the interesting questions are in the supply chain.

> Is it appropriate that an entity (Sweet) is being passed from one domain to another?

No, but a *message* (DTO) describing an entity's state might be passed from one domain to another.

You want to keep the flexibility to define the entities differently in each domain; that's part of the point of identifying bounded contexts.

> Should a Provider be able to reach the StorageCabinet of one domain and pass it's content to another?

Probably not: your domain model isn't the book of record for the storage cabinet.  Listen very carefully to Greg's comments on [one way commands](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDW0QWie21s&t=28m35s).